# Why my formdata.append is not sending key value pair to server?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, apache-commons-fileupload

I think it should be very simple jquery code, but i cant see it pass any result to server. I just want to test string for now, no need for file! In the server, i only see multipart/form-data in request, but parameter field is {}..... Please help...

```
Host: localhost:8888
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 143
Origin: http://localhost:8888
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryUCJkE7tIQ5AqLm74
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:8888/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6
```

and request payload looks like

```
------WebKitFormBoundary93G8teUQTA7hGmxn
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="action"

insert
------WebKitFormBoundary93G8teUQTA7hGmxn--
```

i use java servlet as server side, where

```
String action = request.getParameter("action");
```

retrun null

and below is my code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Distributed Storage System</title>
<script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
    <body>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <form id="form">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="font-weight:bold;">Insert:</td>        
          </tr>
          <tr>        
            <td>Key:<input type="text" id="insertKey" name="key"/></td>
            <td>File:<input type="file" id="insertValue" name="file"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Insert" id="insertValue" onClick="insert()"/></td>        
          </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function insert(){
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append('action','insert');
            //var file = $("#insertValue")[0].files[0];
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open( 'POST', '/distributedstorage', true );
            xhr.send( data );
        }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: looks fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y951t24b/1/ - look at `Request Payload` under `Headers`

Comment: im sorry, but what do you mean "look at Request Payload under Headers"

Comment: yes. Request Payload under Headers

Comment: ok, i check there in my chrome, it shows 
------WebKitFormBoundary93G8teUQTA7hGmxn
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="action"

insert
------WebKitFormBoundary93G8teUQTA7hGmxn--
   looks like it is there, but why my servlet not picking it up?
  String action = request.getParameter("action");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` we should use `FileItem` methods `getFieldName() getString()` to get regular form fields data.
Here I'm providing more details from docs with the snippets, to read all form fields data in `Servelet` using `ServletFileUpload`

**[Give a look into apache-docs for Processing the uploaded items](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html)**

See below code-snip for understanding on this processing:

**Handling uploaded Form elements content both regular fields and files**

```
// Process the uploaded items
Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    FileItem item = iter.next();

    if (item.isFormField()) {
        processFormField(item);
    } else {
        processUploadedFile(item);
    }
}
```

**Process a regular form field**

```
// processFormField
if (item.isFormField()) {
    String name = item.getFieldName();
    String value = item.getString();
    ...
}
```

**Process a file upload**

```
// processUploadedFile
if (!item.isFormField()) {
    String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
    String fileName = item.getName();
    String contentType = item.getContentType();
    boolean isInMemory = item.isInMemory();
    long sizeInBytes = item.getSize();
    ...
}
```

Please proceed rest of the code in http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html